# bootstrap link area smaller on focus and active?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a thumbnail gallery and each of the `<a>` elements have an outline around them, when I click on one of the links, the outline is noticeably shorter (only by a pixel or two but enough to be annoying) than the surrounding elements

link to codepen - http://codepen.io/Davez01d/pen/NxMzYy?editors=1100

here's the html -

```
<div class="row vert-space-30"><!--row-->
      <div id="padding-helper"><!--padding-helper-->
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 port-tile text-center">
          <a class="thumbnail" href="http://codepen.io/Davez01d/full/obyBbz/" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://i1155.photobucket.com/albums/p558/Davez01d/Portfolio%20site-Codepen/f043ed05-0df8-42b9-a7b3-57ad6cab5f3b_zpsq2074gko.png" alt="Pomodoro thumbnail"/>
            <div class="caption">  
              <h4>Pomodoro Timer</h4>
              <p class="tech-used">JavaScript, jQuery, HTML, Css</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 port-tile text-center">
          <a class="thumbnail" href="http://codepen.io/Davez01d/full/JGvdxX/" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://i1155.photobucket.com/albums/p558/Davez01d/Portfolio%20site-Codepen/726c239e-157c-4e4d-8931-77f3a4c9de9c_zpslofzlecy.png" alt="Calculator thumbnail"/>
            <div class="caption">  
              <h4>JavaScript Calculator</h4>
              <p class="tech-used">JavaScript, jQuery, HTML, Css</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 port-tile text-center">
          <a class="thumbnail" href="http://codepen.io/Davez01d/full/gPegpd/" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://i1155.photobucket.com/albums/p558/Davez01d/Portfolio%20site-Codepen/e9b19619-ed3c-4149-ab15-0a039c59f5a7_zps7vmaslo8.png" alt="Quote generator thumbnail"/>
            <div class="caption">  
              <h4>Random Quote Generator</h4>
              <p class="tech-used">jQuery, twitter API</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 port-tile text-center">
          <a class="thumbnail" href="http://codepen.io/Davez01d/full/KVQzwr/" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://i1155.photobucket.com/albums/p558/Davez01d/Portfolio%20site-Codepen/cc4d40ed-a085-43d6-9dde-90c59161b023_zps0ppintnt.png" alt="Web sketchpad thumbnail"/>
            <div class="caption">  
              <h4>Web Sketchpad</h4>
              <p class="tech-used">jQuery, HTML, CSS</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div><!--padding-helper-->
    </div><!--row-->
```

and the css-

```
.port-tile a {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 3px solid #d63c20;
  transition: all .12s ease;
}
.port-tile a:hover {
  z-index: 10;
  outline: 3px solid #d63c20;
  transform: scale(1.12, 1.12);
}
.port-tile a:active, a:focus {
    outline: 3px solid #d63c20;
}
```

Also side-note, I'm finding it hard to find a list of all the bootstrap effects on links, buttons, etc, is there a good resource for this? it would help me out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `a:focus { outline-offset: -2px; }` that I believe you're referring to, which causes this:

[image]

You could override that with your own style, just set

```
a:focus {
    outline-offset: 0;
}
```

if you don't have a need for this rule at all. Or, target the specific elements where you wish to remove it.

Comment: Good to hear. Also, as a resource, I would just get familiar with the documentation on getbootstrap.com, and if you want to explore more, then reference the source css file :)